# Can I Create Entities from Separate Databases in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a EF class with a connection to a sql server database "mydb", I like to update data on another database (suppose mydb2.dbo.anothertable) on same server, Can I create a entity that is related to this "another" database using the same connection?
(excuse me for my grammar errors, I speak in spanish)

Answer (score 0):

Based off [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cad06147-2168-4c20-ac23-98f32987b126), I'd say you're out of luck. You'll have to create a separate ADO Entity item for each database and update using separate connections.

If you want to build a transaction against both of these connections, you can use [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx) to coordinate your transaction.

Comment: thanks 4 reply, I only need to update a single table on another database without a transaction, can I do that?

Comment: Not on the same connection, no. You need two separate ADO Entity repositories, with two separate connections.